# Implementing Malloc: case for splitting a block

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, malloc

The heap is a linked list of structs of the following definition:

```
struct block
{
/*header + block*/
bool freeSpace;
block * prev;
block * next;
size_t size;
char block_part[];
};
```

I'm working on the following case:

**If the first block of memory I find is so big that it can accommodate both the newly allocated
block and another block in addition, then the block is split in two; one block to hold the newly
allocated block, and a residual free block.**

(Note that if it’s a bit larger than what I need, but not big
enough for a new block (i.e. it’s not big enough to hold the metadata of a new block), I will have unused space at the end of the block.)

My code is the following. When I test specifically this case, my program crashes with a segfault. Could someone see what the problem is? Thanks.

```
do{
    if (ptr -> freeSpace && ptr -> size >= size){
        /*first suffient free block is found*/
        ptr -> freeSpace = false;

        if (ptr -> size > size + sizeof(struct  block)){
            /*if big enought for 'size' AND metadata of a new block, split the block*/
            struct block * returnPtr = memset((ptr -> block_part), 0, size);
            struct block * added = returnPtr + size;
            added -> size = ptr -> size - size - sizeof(struct block);
            added -> freeSpace = true;
            added -> prev = ptr;
            added -> next = ptr -> next;
            (ptr -> next) -> prev = added;
            ptr -> next = added;
            ptr -> size = size;
            return returnPtr;

            }
        ptr -> size = size;
        return memset((ptr -> block_part), 0, size);

        }
    prevPtr = ptr;
    ptr = ptr -> next;


}while (ptr);
```

Comment: Surely you only split a block when you can't find any block that is large enough? And please remove the spaces each side of the `->`

Comment: That's not when I split. I split when I find a block that is too large. @WeatherVane

Comment: I suggest you add the size of metadata to the memory requirement before you begin.

Comment: *" I split when I find a block that is too large."* will rapidly fragment your pool, which is why you look for the smallest block that is large enough. My first comment was badly written.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memset returns a `void *`. It doesn't give warning because void pointers are automatically casted by the Compiler (e.g. `malloc` (*non-*)cast).

```
struct block *returnPtr = memset((ptr->block_part), 0, size);
```

Why would you *waste* memory for a whole struct with multiple members to store a void pointer pointing to character?

After that you use the address of the **now** void pointer and move it `size`-number forwards. Afterwards treat it like an allocated struct. That results in `added` not being allocated at all (if `size` is bigger than `strlen(ptr->block_part)+1` you are already at someone other's memory) or at least violating memory. Accessing such memory gives so an erroneous program.

Hence, you observe segmentation fault and you program crashes.

---

*Note*: So far, I haven't seen someone use in such way the `memset` return value.

Comment: "Note: So far, I haven't seen someone use in such way the memset return value" - I've read that a lot but there isn't anything wrong with it,really, is there?

Comment: Are you saying changing block * returnPtr to char * returnPtr will solve my problem?

Comment: Yes, because `memset` returns `void *` and the argument, namely `ptr->block_part`, is `char *`. The conversion (`void *` to `char *`) happens implicitly because 1) `void *` can be converted to any other back and again and 2) in pre-ANSI C there was no `void *`, `char *` was used instead (compatibility). But here, yet again, it depends on the argument.